# Changing integer of year and week to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

how can I convert a lot of data in a dataframe from an integer to a datetime? But I only have Year and Week data like the example. The column is named 'Year_Week' and should be tranformed complete.

```
for example:
Year_Week
201601
201602
201603
...
201652
```

so ist should be converted like this:

```
201601 = 2016-01-01
201602 = 2016-01-08
```

My data is integer, so I converted it to object.

```
df.Year_Week = df.Year_Week.astype(str)
```

And then I tried

```
dateString = df['Year_Week']
dateObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateString + '-1', "%Y%W-%w")
print(dateObject)

But there is a TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

Do not know how to fix it, because I tried to convert it from integer to string, but it became an object... 
Now i don't know where my fault is

Thank you for help

Comment: you need `pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + '0',format='%Y%W%w')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datetime.datetime.strptime(dateString + '-1', "%Y%W-%w") parameter only looks at one string object. To convert whole series into datetime, you need to do something like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Week']+ '-1',format="%Y%W-%w")
```

Comment: hmm I tried it, but that does not change something in my case

Comment: The command given only **displays** the changed content. Another detail is that explicit conversion to *string* is required. To sum up, run *df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Year_Week.astype(str) + '-1',format="%Y%W-%w")*